# How to pop up a text file in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

This small program shows how to open a txt file on the hard drive, is there a way I can have a procedure that when I click a button a txt file pops up, may someone help me with it or how I can go about it....

This is the procedure below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
    of.ShowDialog();
    textBox1.Text = of.FileName;
}
```

May somebody tell me what I can do or give some material to read kind of new in C#

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do? Do you want to have a new window appear with, say, a multi-line text box that contains the contents of a text file?

Comment: you code shows that file name with full path is displaying in textbox.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you like opening notepad with the text file showing on it, you could use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(of.FileName);
```

This will open the file using the default text editor of the computer.

**EDIT**

According to your comment, you should the do it like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\dir1\dir2\yourfile.txt");
}
```

Obviusly, you should replace that with the path for your specific file.

Comment: -this one works but i do not want to include the testbox or look for a file to open,i just want it to open the txt file only one text file automatically without passing through the txt box,upon clicking a button a file should open one specific file

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
MessageBox.Show(File.ReadAllText(of.FileName));
```

After it, try to learn each component of the statement, what it does.

BTW,

You also need:

```
if (of.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```

before that, to avoid displaying message in case user clicks Cancel.

Comment: im getting some errors what exactly should i do?should i paste it under the code abot in the question?

Comment: I'm glad that you are getting some errors, because you have nice opportunity to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the clarification, this is pretty straightforward. Just create a new form class that contains a textbox (and probably a Close button). You'll want a property on the form that will set the textbox. You can launch the this form from your button event handler (the one you have in your example) like this:

```
using(var myForm = new TextBoxForm()) {
    myForm.TextFileContents = <file contents>
    myForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

As for reading in the file contents, you'll want to use `File.ReadAllText()` as described in Daniel's answer. See the MSDN documentation for more on that. I'll leave the remaining details as an exercise to the reader.